# ASP.NET Wizard Control Save state

Tags: c#, asp.net, state, wizard

I use the wizard control and want to save the state.

My Problem is that the last state is gone, if a user for example goes to another page and the clicks the back button of the browser.

Of course i can save all settings done by the user in a session but i want to ask if there is an easier way to save the state?

Comment: what asp.net web development method are you using, mvc, webforms webpages?

Comment: The state of controls are only maintained during postbacks.

Comment: i use webforms. so the only solution is to save the state in a session?